# Yii2 Kartik widgets do not work after integrated with AdminLTE Theme

Tags: yii2, adminlte, kartik-v

FileInput works fine with yii2 default theme.
But after change to AdminLTE Theme, almost Kartik-v widget does not work.
Anyone know problem and solution ?

```
namespace app\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;
class AdminLTEAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'themes/AdminLTE/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css',
        "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css",
        "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css",
        'themes/AdminLTE/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css',
        'themes/AdminLTE/dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css',
        'themes/AdminLTE/plugins/iCheck/flat/blue.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
        'themes/AdminLTE/plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js',
        'themes/AdminLTE/plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.all.min.js',
        "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js",
        'themes/AdminLTE/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js',
        "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js",
        'themes/AdminLTE/plugins/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js',
        'themes/AdminLTE/plugins/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js',
        'themes/AdminLTE/plugins/fastclick/fastclick.js',
        'themes/AdminLTE/dist/js/app.min.js',
        'themes/AdminLTE/dist/js/pages/dashboard.js',
        'themes/AdminLTE/dist/js/demo.js',

    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',

    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by removing this line:

```
'themes/AdminLTE/plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js',
```